# Debug Azure Germany with different Account

Tags: azure

We recently changed our existing Azure subscription to Azure Germany and got a new account like `name@company.onmicrosoft.de`. Afaik this kind of domain is also used for Ofice365 accounts. Now i tried to add this account to my Visual Studio (2015 Community Edition), but i get this error (translated from german):

> The account "" could not be added. Object reference not set to an object instance.

On the classic US Azure subscription we worked with our regular domain-Logins (`name@company.de`). Does anybody know how to connect to my new azure subscription, so that i can browse and debug? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it might be a surprise for you, but almost nobody knows German, and a translation would be nice

Comment: Now with translated error message ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

As far as I know, it is not possible to add Azure Germany accounts to Visual Studio. But there are some workarounds for common tasks you do with Visual Studio.
According to Microsoft Technical Evangelist Malte Lantin, there seems to be something hardcoded in Visual Studio, that prevents VS from connecting to Azure Germany.

### Workarounds

#### Deploy a solution

Download the publishing profile in Azure Portal and use it to deploy your solution

#### View SQL Databases

Navigate to the Azure Portal and click, view in Visual Studio

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I already did the deployment this way and was looking for a solution to live-debug my azure instance...  i guess i need to setup some local test situations...